# SQL statement to update columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How I can add a column in a sql parameter on laravel 5.3?

I have a table with: `id,name,zipcode,nearag1` and a variable named `agent`

I want a SQL statement for laravel 5.3 like this:

```
*UPDATE items set near_ag1=ABS(zipcode-$agent)* traslate to laravel 5.3
```

I made a SQL raw statement like this:

```
$Agzc1= $request2->input('Agzc1');

Item::raw("UPDATE items set near_ag1=ABS(zipcode-?)",[$Agzc1]);
```

This SQL produces no errors but the column `near_ag1` is saving 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method for bindings, and you should not go full raw, so:

```
Item::update(['near_ag1' => DB::raw('ABS(zipcode-?)'))->setBindings([$Agzc1]);
```